# How to reject http/https request if not coming from allowed website or source

Tags: rest, express, http, request, http-post

I have an api service: `my-api.com/getData` 
My api expects an `api-key` from customer to authenticate the request.
My customer's front-end hosted on: `customer.com` 
My customer's back-end hosted on: `customer-backend.com`
There is no Log-in option in customer's website

**Scenario** 
In *customer's* website, a button sends request to `customer-backend.com/use-my-api` 
This request executes `post('my-api.com/getData', api-key)` in backend 
So *visitor* gets data and *visitor* is not able to see `api-key` of my *customer*.

**Problem** 
When a smart third guy uses `post('customer-backend.com/use-my-api')`
in his own website or back-end. He gets data without providing `api-key` 
This is a very unwanted situation for my customer

**Question** 
How can we reject all requests from outside of the allowed website or source. Changing the architecture of service is not a problem for me and my customer.
As far as i know checking request headers for `host` is not a reliable. Since it can be changed by sender easily.

Comment: You seem to say that a visitor's browser shall access the endpoint `customer-backend.com/use-my-api` (coming from the customer's website), but a "smart third guy" shall not be able to access the same endpoint. But you cannot distinguish between these two cases, unless the customer's website and backend require a log-in.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen You understood the problem very well. There is no log-in function in website. Api call must work with or without log-in

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP request does not come "from a website", but it comes from an HTTP client, for example, a browser that is visiting the website. In order to prevent unauthorized requests, your customer's backend must issue a "secret" to the HTTP client, which the client must then include in the request.

A common technique to achieve this is the following:

- Visitors must log-in to your customer's website.
- After successful logon, your customer's backend sends a session cookie to the visitor's browser (this cookie is the "secret", because it is visible only to the visitor and cannot be guessed by "smart third guys").
- The request which the visitor makes by pressing a button includes the session cookie.
- When your customer's backend (`customer-backend.com/use-my-api`) receives a request, it validates the session cookie before making the `post('my-api.com/getData', api-key)`.

Without a log-in mechanism or something equivalent, your customer's website is public and can be (mis-)used by anyone, even if that leads to (paid) API requests made with the customer's API key.